# Python eval integer in string, and return integer instead of ascii char

Tags: python, integer, ascii, eval

I'm getting some data from a file, which looks like this:

```
[200, "Hello", "World"]
```

Now, since this is a file, this array is inside a string; I turn it into an array using `eval()`.
This works fine BUT the integer at the start is converted to an ascii char, instead of an integer as I want it to (the euro sign).

How can I fix this?

Comment: This worked fine for me. >>> z = eval("[200, \"hello\", \"world\"]")
>>> z
[200, 'hello', 'world']

Comment: @Judge John Deed ascii char ? Which ascii char ? I don't observe what you describe

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [simplejson](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson/) module. E.g.

```
>>> import simplejson
>>> a = simplejson.loads('[200, "Hello", "World"]')
>>> print a
[200, 'Hello', 'World']
```

This way "malicious" data such as `os.execvp()` would not be evaluated but an `JSONDecodeError`would be thrown.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `literal_eval`. Really depends on the source - is the source speaking Python or JSON - there is a lot of overlap where they have identical representations

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> literal_eval('[200, "Hello", "World"]')
[200, 'Hello', 'World']
```